# How to fix (CS0019) operator "!=" cannot be applied to operands of type "Random" and "int"

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a mind game where the player tries to guess a number between 2 numbers of their choice but I keep getting the error on title.

Code - MRE:

```
Random guessedNum = new Random();
int answer = 42;

if (guessedNum != answer)       //error is here
{}
```

> (CS0019) operator "!=" cannot be applied to operands of type "Random" and "int"

Original code:

```
Console.WriteLine("choose the first number");
int firstNum = 0;
firstNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Choose the second number");
int secondNum = 0;
secondNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Random guessedNum = new Random();
guessedNum.Next(firstNum, secondNum);

Console.WriteLine($"write a number between {firstNum} and {secondNum}.");
int answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if(guessedNum != answer){
    //error is here
}
```

Comment: `guessedNum` is not the random number, it's the generator. `guessedNum.Next(...)` returns the random number but you don't save the value it returns.

Comment: I see, ok I fixed it thanks.

Comment: @youssefcraft Welcome to StackOverflow. I edited your question to the [mre]. Please, read about it so your next questions are more fit to SO. Also, when writing questions and answers, we shouldn't add things like "Hello", "Thanks", "Please help", those are considered noise. Post in the most impersonal form possible, focusing on you issue.

Comment: @Magnetron note that you did not actually provide [MRE] - `new Random() == 42` is truly minimal, even if you want to keep variables still all console reading should be removed. Editing to show.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov true, actually I just removed unecessary code, to make it the minimal possible, without changing OPs code. But yeah, if it was to show OP how to make a mre I should have done like what you did. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing lines 74 and 75 to the following:

```
Random rand = new Random();
var guessedNum = rand.Next(firstNum, secondNum);
```

Just as a quick explanation, the symbol `=` is called the assignment operator. It takes whatever is calculated or generated on the right side and puts it into the spot in memory that is named on the left side. In your original code, you took a random number and didn't assign it to any spot in memory. In my suggested edit, I took the random number and assigned it to a spot in memory that I named `guessedNum`.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: @youssefcraft if that solved your issue, you should mark it as the accepted answer. That's how you mark a question as "solved" on Stack Overflow, not editing the title.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: @youssefcraft bellow the answer voting there is a gray check mark, just click it and it will turn green.